# ObservableCollection<DateTime> and updating the UI when the item changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `ObservableCollection<DateTime>` property named `Dates`.

Is there any way to update the UI when I do something like `Dates[0] = DateTime.Today`.

Or the only way is to put this in a new class and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on it? Then I would have to do `Dates[0].Date = DateTime.Today`

I don't want to re-assign the collection or clear the list and then add items again. It works that way but is a performance bottleneck because ItemsControl takes long to render.

Comment: `Dates[0] = DateTime.Today` fires the CollectionChanged event and should hence update the UI.

Comment: Can't you just manually call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Dates))` ?

Comment: @Clemens it doesn't I bind to `Dates` elsewhere and it works only when I replace the collection or `Add` or `Remove` items.

Comment: @iSpain17 That wouldn't help for updating individual items.

Comment: Well, it does fire the event. What control/property is bound to Dates?

Comment: `TextBlock.Text` it looks like `Text="{Binding ElementName=ScheduleView, Path=Dates, Converter={StaticResource MonthYearDisplayConverter}}"`

Comment: Then maybe remove the item, then add it. But pay attention to the index from which you deleted it (so use `.Insert` instead of `.Add`) - that is better than reassigning the entire collection

Comment: yup. that's why I upvoted your first comment in the first place. Because you can't do it in an easier way.

Comment: @Konrad A TextBlock does of course not register a CollectionChanged event handler. With `Path=Dates`, you have to assign a **new** collection instance to the property. Anything else won't work, because the value of the Dates property has to change to trigger the Binding.

Comment: @Clemens that's a pity. Is there any way to make this work? Assigning new collection causes performance problems.

Comment: That depends on what you want to display. What is your MonthYearDisplayConverter doing?

Comment: It's showing the currently displayed months and year, e.g. "June - July 2019" or "December 2019 - January 2020"

Comment: So there are only two items in the collection?

Comment: @Clemens the list has 7 items (dates), for displaying a week. It's showing months and year for the current week (1 week can end or begin in a different month). I wanted to make this list fixed and only replace dates with indexer for better performance. Replacing the entire collection causes 1-2 sec freezes in the UI because controls have to re-render from scratch

Comment: You could perhaps just add another property to your view model that returns the date range.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use the INotifyPropertyChanged on a Object and use Bindings the properties of that Object.

For example, having this object:

```
public class Dates : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _myDate;
    public DateTime MyDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _myDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _myDate = value;
            // With this NotifyPropertyChanged it will raise the event that it has changed and update the information where there is a binding for this property
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDate");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

When you set a new value for the DateTime it will notify the UI there is a change and it will update it.

A more practical example, I have this on a program, an object with several properties.

```
/// <summary>
/// Total price for this line without VAT
/// </summary>
public float PriceTotalWithoutVAT
{
    get
    {
        return (float)Math.Round(this.Qtd * (this.PricePerUnit - (this.PricePerUnit * (this.Discount / 100))), 2);
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Returns the value of <seealso cref="PriceTotalWithoutVAT"/> as string with only 2 decimal places
/// </summary>
public string GetPriceTotalWithoutVat
{
    get
    {
        return this.PriceTotalWithoutVAT.ToString("0.00") + RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.CurrencySymbol;
    }
}
```

And we have the property with the set here:

```
/// <summary>
/// Quantity for the line
/// </summary>
public float Qtd
{
    get
    {
        return this._qtd;
    }
    set
    {
        this._qtd = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Qtd");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("PriceTotalWithoutVAT");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("GetPriceTotalWithoutVat");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("PriceTotalWithVAT");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("GetPriceTotalWithVAT");
    }
}
```

When on the WPF the TextBox bellow the value changes AKA the property Qtd it will update the information on the UI for the other ones

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxLineQtd" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Qtd}" Width="70" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" PreviewTextInput="ValidateNumericDecimal_PreviewTextInput"/>
```

this 2 TextBox are updated with the new information

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxLineTotalWihtoutVat" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding GetPriceTotalWithoutVat, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False"/>
<TextBox Name="TextBoxLineTotalWihtVat" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding GetPriceTotalWithVAT, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False"/>
```

Hope that this helped out, if you guys see any improvement on the code that I have put here to tell :D